# How to set drawable background in ViewHolder Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-viewholder

Im trying Read call log application Im changing call type to missed outgoing incoming using call type I want to change img according to that

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        TextView number, duration, type, date;
        Drawable img_type, img_type_user;

        number = holder.number;
        type = holder.type;
        date = holder.date;
        duration = holder.duration;

        img_type = holder.img_type;
        img_type_user = holder.img_type_user;

        number.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getNumber());
        type.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getType());
        date.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getDate());
        duration.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getDuration());

        //set drawable

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return newlistCalls.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView number, type, date, duration;
        Drawable img_type, img_type_user;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            duration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

            img_type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_type_image).getBackground();
            img_type_user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_image).getBackground();

        }
    }
```

Please help me this Im a newbie on Android Studio

Comment: Set the drawable to the cardview?

Comment: `img_type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_type_image).getBackground();` Does this thing has drawable value in it? And where will you set the drawable, you must have an imageView. Do you have `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

If `newlistCalls.get(position).getType()` contains string of call types as:

- missed
- outgoing
- incoming

And you have all types of images inside your `drawables`. You can write a method inside your Adapter to get background image from your `drawables` as below:

```
private int getBackgroundImageFromCallType(String type) {
    switch (type) {
        case "missed":
            return R.drawable.ic_missed;
        case "outgoing":
            return R.drawable.ic_outgoing;
        case "incoming":
            return R.drawable.ic_incoming;
        default:
            return R.drawable.ic_call_placeholder;
    }
}
```

and use it inside your `onBindViewHolder`.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.number.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getNumber());
    holder.type.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getType());
    holder.date.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getDate());
    holder.duration.setText(newlistCalls.get(position).getDuration());
    holder.img_type.setImageResource(getBackgroundImageFromCallType(newlistCalls.get(position).getType()));
}
```

Comment: try that but it didnt change the images after few seconds app crash

Comment: Did you placed `ic_missed`, `ic_outgoing`, `ic_incoming` and `ic_call_placeholder` into your drawable folders? Please share crashlog from logcat.

Comment: Yes I have include all the files but it didnt work. Please help me

Comment: Share crashlog for more clarification.